# SSIS File System Task - Copy Directory failed as file name or directory already exist

Tags: sql, ssis, filesystems

I have 2 SSIS packages. 
Package1 generates 10 files in each folder in source directory. 
Package2 generates 1 file in each folder in source directory. 
Ex.

```
\\Source_Directory\folder1
\\Source_Directory\folder2
\\Source_Directory\folder3
\\Source_Directory\folder4
```

Package1 just generate files in the source directory files.
Package2 which contains for each loop container and file system task. 
The file system task (Copy Directory), copy all the files from source directory folders to destination directory folders.
The file system task has property OverwriteDestination file as "True"
Ex.

```
\\Destination_Directory\folder1
\\Destination_Directory\folder2
\\Destination_Directory\folder3
\\Destination_Directory\folder4
```

The package1 executed successfully and when package2 execute for each loop container, files are copied from source folder1 to destination folder1 (overwriten in destination). 
In the next loop, while copying the file from source folder2 to destination folder2, the package gets failed as "because the file name or directory exists already."

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is it not set to overwrite the previous version or add a date to the file name?

Comment: It is set to overwrite the destination file. And, date is not added to the file name.